# A question about a macro definition error

Tags: macros, errors, books

Given:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\emrule}[1]{\rule[4pt]{#1em}{0.2pt}}
\newcommand{\endash}{\emrule{.5}}
\begin{document}
2000\endash2013
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \endash already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \newcommand{\endash}{\emrule{.5}}

?
```

So my first question is what manual---`see p.192 of the manual.`?
Through experimentation I believe that what is going on here is a name clash. The processor sees `\end` and hits the brake with an attendent error message. For instance `\EMdash` and `\enrule` both work without error. Since I lack sufficient macro-foo, could someone with greater knowledge than I please clarify? BTW if I comment out the definition of `\endash` it fails with a message about `\endash` not defined:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 2000\endash
               2013
?
```

Which leads me back to my contention that this is a name clash with just `\end`.

Comment: You could try just changing the name. I tend to start my macros with an uppercase letter and a prefix -- although this is not guaranteed to _always_ work, I haven't had a problem yet.  So for example something like `\HSEndash`, `\HSEmdash`, `\HSMyMacro`, etc.

Comment: @PeterGrill note that I said that `\EMdash` or for that matter `ENdash` both work. I'm not looking for a fix, just an explanation, thanks though.

Comment: :-) I guess I really should read the question. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Slashdot idiom would be RTFQ, but I've always found that a bit rude :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\newcommand` explicitly refuses to define macros whose name begins with `end`. This may have been a disputable design decision, but the LaTeX kernel is kind of frozen and changing this behavior after so many years would open big problems. With `\NewDocumentCommand` from the `xparse` package you're freed from this restriction:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\endash}{}{\emrule{.5}}
```

Another way can be to test if the command already exists in a different way:

```
\unless\ifdefined\endash
  \def\endash{\emrule{.5}}
\fi
```

relying on lower level TeX constructions.

Are there any problems with this? Yes, there are. If you later on say

```
\newenvironment{ash}
 {something maybe related to cricket at the start}
 {something else at the end}
```

you'd find yourself in big trouble, because this declaration would silently redefine your `\endash` command: indeed the `ash` environment uses `\ash` and `\endash` at start and finish.

Comment: Extremely good to know! I've suffered from this disease in virtually every compiler I've used---And I've used a lot. Can't quite see why folks seem to miss the notion that they shouldn't place restrictions on users particularly by accident! <sigh/> BTW, I not particularly happy about no numbers is macro names either...

Comment: @hsmyers Numbers in macro names would pose difficult problems; remember that TeX is primarily a language for typesetting, so some limitations are present for reasons related to this primary task (or because of Knuth's view of it). The "`end`" restriction is due to how environments are implemented. If later you define an `ash` environment, you'd be in big troubles.

Comment: Also good to know. Could you explain what manual the reference mentions? I'd guess ***LaTeX Companion***, but I'd like to know for sure (likewise what edition).

Comment: @hsmyers The manual referred to is "LaTeX, a document preparation system" by L. Lamport (the original author of LaTeX).

Comment: That would explain why the page didn't seem to be in context. Good thing I've got both :)